# How to give a geometric proof for the volume of the parallelopiped?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

In linear algebra, it is known that the scalar product
$$
V = | (\vec{a} \times \vec{b})   \cdot \vec{c} | =
\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\[1mm]
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\[1mm]
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\[1mm]
 \end{array} \right|
$$
represents the volume of the parallelopiped  with $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and
$\vec{c}$ as the three sides.

1. How to prove this result geometrically?
2. If $V = 0$, then the volume $V$ of the parallelopiped is zero. This means that
   $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are coplanar.

[image: Vector Algebra]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general,
$$V=\text{Area}\cdot \text{height}=\underbrace{|\vec{a}\times \vec{b}|}_{\text{Area}}\cdot \underbrace{|\vec{c}|\cdot \cos(\phi)}_{\text{height}}=(\vec{a}\times \vec{b})\cdot \vec{c}$$

[image]

Comment: Good, but there is a mistake in the picture: it seems to suggest that the face the contains $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf c$ is vertical, while it's not true in general, and the angle $\phi$ is not measured in a plane that contains $\mathbf a$ (i.e., $\mathbf a$, $\mathbf c$ and $\mathbf a\times \mathbf b$ are not coplanar).

Comment: You're right. See here for a better picture: https://www.mathelike.de/media/k2/items/cache/37d163b88a4522bd852de06260df3d98_L.jpg

Comment: Hi @racine_carree, this is unrelated to your answer, hence I would be deleting this comment soonest. Please could you help out with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4435979/585488